# Best model for longitudinal analysis

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data

I have one dependent variable and multiple predictors. Dependent is continuous and predictors may be continuous or dichotomous.

My sample is of 200 individuals. Each month, for 6 months, I have a measure of predictors for the 200 individuals and I would like to identify those which have a significant effect over the dependent variable.

My problem is that I only have one yearly measure for the dependent variable. This variable is a judgment about the service provided and is given once a year.

Is there a good model you would suggest to take into account repeated measures over time (independent variables) and their influence on a single measured dependent variable?

Answer (score 1):

(This would be more appropriate for a comment but I do not have enough reputation to comment.)

I think you have to start by defining which kind of impact the measurement of the independent variable is expected to have on the dependent one. Can it be that it is merely a cumulative effect of some of the predictors? Or can it depend on how a predictor or group of predictors change with time? To test the former is much easier than the latter, and I think you need to define what you want to test, i.e., formulate the question you want to answer, before moving any further and starting to search for models.

Comment: Yes, in this case it could be a cumulative effect. The question would be the general one "are predictors significantly affecting the customer satisfaction score?". Any suggestion?

Comment: If the idea is to test the cumulative effect I would effectively reduce the data complexity by collapsing the measurement on each the predictors into a number, and move to consider each of them as an independent variable. This would make the problem much easier to tackle and you can, for instance, apply a multivariate linear regression (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_linear_regression) on each of the independent variables to get a first impression on what is their impact on the dependent one.

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking of something like that. Collapsing with a mean would make sense? (summing would not be possible since I have some missing data).

Comment: Yes, I would say it should. You can also consider the median if you want to minimize the impact of outliers.